# How can I transfer some values from one class to another?

Tags: java, class, java.util.scanner, composition

Firstly I have 3 classes with getters and setters. In the Main class I scan two variables of type `int` called `rows` and `columns`, which are in turn used to initialise an instance of the `Airplane` class. After this I want to calculate the product of these variables in class `Flight`. So I gave the values `rows = 2` and `columns = 3` and it printed `0` to the `console`. Every different value I give keeps returning `0` as a result. Your help will be appreciated!
Here is my code:

Main class:

```
  public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           int counter=1;
           if (counter==1) {
               Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
               int rows, columns;
               Airplane airplane = new Airplane();
               rows = scanner.nextInt();
               airplane.setRows(rows);
               columns = scanner.nextInt();
               airplane.setColumns(columns);
               System.out.println(airplane.getColumns()*airplane.getRows());
               counter++;
           }
           if (counter==2){
                   Flight flight = new Flight();
                   int seats=0;
                   seats=flight.getNumberOfSeats();
                   System.out.println(seats);
            }
    }
}
```

Flight class:

```
public class Flight {
    private int numberOfSeats;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Airplane class:

```
public class Airplane {
    private int rows;
    private int columns;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible (maybe post the rest of classes `Airplane` and `Flight`). This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Comment: Show us your setters please. I think you're not setting the member variables correctly

Comment: Can you tell us the (contextual) relation between `Flight` and `Airplane`?

Comment: You use `getNumberOfSeats()` on a fresh new `Flight` object. if `numberOfSeats` is not edited its default value is 0.

Answer (score 1):

In the second if statement you created a new instance of `Flight` and you haven't changed any of its field values, so consequently when you are reading the number of seats here it still has the initial value 0 (the default value for an int).
The code below should do what you want.

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int counter=1;
       Airplane airplane;
       if (counter==1) {
           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
           int rows, columns;
           airplane = new Airplane();
           rows = scanner.nextInt();
           airplane.setRows(rows);
           columns = scanner.nextInt();
           airplane.setColumns(columns);
           System.out.println(airplane.getColumns()*airplane.getRows());
           counter++;
       }
       if (counter==2) {
           Flight flight = new Flight();
           flight.setNumberOfSeats(airplane.getColumns()*airplane.getRows());
           System.out.println(flight.getNumberOfSeats());
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an exercise in [polymorphism and composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). It is likely that the idea is that a `Flight` has an `Airplane` [HAS-A relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a). Your `Flight` class will than look like this:

```
class Flight {
  private Airplane airplane;
  private int numberOfSeats;

  public Flight(Airplane airplane) {
    this.airplane = airplane;
    this.numberOfSeats = (airplane.getColumns() * airplane.getRows());
  }

  public void getNumberOfSeats() {
     return this.numberOfSeats;
  }


  public void setNumberOfSeats(int numberOfSeats) {
    this.numberOfSeats = numberOfSeats;
  }
}
```

In your main code you now only have to pass the reverence of the `Airplane` to the `Flight`.

`Flight flight = new Flight(airPlane);`

Since you already defined the plane outside the `if` scope this can be done, if you change it to `Airplane airplane = null;`